# Is this statement about preimage and image always true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ and let $C$ be a subset of $X$. Can we always state that $f^{−1}(f(C))$ is a subset of $C$?

Is this always true or not? And how can I prove this?

Comment: If $x \in f^{-1}(C)$, then by definition $f(x) \in C$, so yes, it's true.

Comment: What does $f^{-1}(C)$ mean when $C$ is a subset of the domain of $f$?

Comment: Maybe you meant $f^{-1}(f(C))$, which is not necessarily a subset of $C$.

Comment: I have mistaken the statment. f^{−1}(f(C)) is a subset of C - this should be proved

Comment: No, it's the other way round.

Comment: $C$ is a subset of $f^{-1}(f(C))$. Just think about a constant function as an easy example, and it should already give you a lot of intuition.

Comment: The statement $f^{−1}\big[f[C]\big] \subset C$ would mean that whenever we have an element $x \in X$ that maps to the same element of $Y$ as some element $x' \in C$ does, then $x$ itself must be in $C$.  Does this seem true?  Or could there be an element of $y$ that is the image of an element $x' \in C$ and also the image of an element $x \in X \setminus C$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Consider the case $X=\{a,b\}$, $Y=\{c\}$. There is only one function $X\to Y$, try $C=\{a\}$.

Comment: Sorry,I don't get it. Could you explain this?

Comment: @user2013804: Have you tried calculating $f^{-1}[f[C]]$ in this example?

Comment: No, because I don't know which is the function for which Kars Kronenfeld is talking.

Comment: @user2013804 Pick any function from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @user2013804 To specify a function $f$ on the set $\{a,b\}$, one would specify its values $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.  If $f$ is a function into the set $\{c\}$ then these values both lie in the set $\{c\}$, so they must both be equal to $c$.  I think you should practice listing _all_ the functions between two given finite sets (say $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{4,5\}$) before attempting problems like the one in your post, because this is a good way to find counterexamples.